# How rewrite htacess properly on these case?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im pretty new in htaccess and I got some trouble on these case

1. I need to do a 301 redirect this specific URL only :

> example.com/jobs to example.com/browse-jobs

if the url is example.com/jobs/job1 it will not redirect.

2. Redirect all the URL have path /product to /package. E.g : example.com/product and example.com/product/1, all of these URL will redirect to example.com/package.
3. Rewrite URL :

   example.com/browse-jobs/?job_type=internship rewrite to example.com/browse-jobs/intership.

If URL example.com/browse-jobs/?posted=14days&job_type=internship do not rewrite and keep it the same.

I struggle with these case entire a day, I check all the reference website and still don't know how to make it right. If someone know about this please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been experimenting, I'd suggest clearing your cache, maybe restart apache:

```
RewriteBase /
# product, products, product/abc, product/a/b/c to package
# If you don't want products to redirect, add $ after the ?
RewriteRule ^product(/.*)? package [R=301]

# Exactly jobs with or without / to browse-jobs
RewriteRule ^jobs/?$ browse-jobs [R=301]

# If query string only contains parameter job_type with value internship    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^job_type=(internship)$
# With or without slash    
RewriteRule ^(browse-jobs)/?$ $1/%1 [QSD,R=301]
# QSD = Discard the query string
```

Comment: Im not sure why but when I tried, do I need to put this inside the  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>?

Comment: @DanielStark it's safer that way but not necessary if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled for sure.